# Using a Regex for JavaScript source in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to include the different Angular libraries in my HTML document without having to update the HTML every time there is a new production build (after running `ng build --prod`).

For example, my HTML might have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/inline.1e6a76aaeff55d4a7804.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/polyfills.62cd0a749311c6ac36ca.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/vendor.30638605f5fb537724b2.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/main.cd0110b4598ac39daa25.bundle.js"></script>
```

but the strings always change. I've tried to set the import dynamically a few ways with regular expressions to no avail.

For example,

```
<script>document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/inline.' + /^[a-z0-9]+$/i + '.bundle.js"></script>')</script>
```

led to the script tag ending in the wrong place, so I tried:

```
<script>document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/inline.' + /^[a-z0-9]+$/i + '.bundle.js"></scr' + 'ipt>')</script>
```

which let it to be rendered on the page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/dist/inline./^[a-z0-9]+$/i.bundle.js"></script>
```

and then I tried:

```
<script>
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'themes/ng/dist/inline.' + /^[a-z0-9]+$/i + '.bundle.js';
  document.write(script.outerHTML);
</script>
```

which had the same results.

I know I could always use the `index.html` generated with the production build, but with the way the Angular frontend is being implemented as a Drupal theme, that solution would also require rewriting parts of the HTML each time.

Is there a way to use regular expressions to require outside documents (CSS and JavaScript) inside HTML?

Comment: *I want to include the different Angular libraries in my HTML document without having to update the HTML every time there is a new production build* Look into caching. You can also look into CDNs. Since angular is a widely used framework, it must be cached already

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem here. If you cannot just generate the HTML pages with the correct imports on the fly, then just generate all artefacts of the build process with the SAME name, e.g., "inline.bundle.js" instead of having the numbers there. Also, add a header, to prevent the browser caching them. That way you don't need to re-generate the HTML. It should be simpler than using JS to request unknown things.

Comment: @vlaz I didn't even know about the --output-hashing flag. Thanks!

Comment: A regex can't guess the dynamic string but returns true/false based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

One time I had to change the Css files (that would effect the entire layout) in my project depending on the users choice. Although this might not be exactly you are looking for, it can help you with the approach.

I did it this way:

**step 1: I have assigned ID's to the  elements**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="styletarget1" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="styletarget2" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
```

**step 2: I have used the button click event to change the href attribute of the  tag**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#themeDropDown li a").click( function() {
            var themeOption = $(this).attr("value");
            $("#styletarget1").attr("href", 'https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.'+ themeOption +'.min.css');
            $("#styletarget2").attr("href", 'https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/kendo.'+ themeOption +'.mobile.min.css');
        });
}
```

Hope this helps.